Trying to get the yesterday high and low drawn on today chart along with percentages
Im having issues with my mql5 script to get the previous days high and low and display it on the next day along with the 25%, 50% and 75%. The high and low sometimes don't cover the entire day and the percentages dont display at all. Also i would like a vertical line to connect all together like a box. i'm unsure how to do this.
void OnStart()
  {
   // Define variables
   double high, low;
   datetime startTime, endTime;
   int range;
   int i = 1; // Start from the previous day

   // Loop through the previous days
   while (true)
     {
      // Get the high and low of the previous day
      high = iHigh(NULL, PERIOD_D1, i);
      low = iLow(NULL, PERIOD_D1, i);
      range = int(high - low);
      
      //Calculate the percentile
      double P_25, P_50, P_75;
      
      P_25 = NormalizeDoubleFunction((low + (range * 25/100)));
      P_50 = NormalizeDoubleFunction((low + (range * 50/100)));
      P_75 = NormalizeDoubleFunction((low + (range * 75/100)));
      
      double point = SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_POINT);
      
      
      startTime = iTime(NULL, PERIOD_D1, i) + 24 * 60 * 60; // Start time is the next day
      endTime = startTime + 24 * 60 * 60; // End time is the end of the next day

      // Break the loop if no more data
      if (startTime == 0) break;

      // Draw lines on the chart
      string highLineName = "PrevDayHigh_" + IntegerToString(i);
      string lowLineName = "PrevDayLow_" + IntegerToString(i);
      string P_25_Name = "25%" + IntegerToString(i);
      string P_50_Name = "50%" + IntegerToString(i);
      string P_75_Name = "75%" + IntegerToString(i);
      string startVertical = "Start vertical";
      string endVertical = "End Vertical";
      
      ObjectCreate(0, highLineName, OBJ_TREND, 0, startTime, high, endTime, high);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, highLineName, OBJPROP_COLOR, clrRed);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, highLineName, OBJPROP_WIDTH, 1);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, highLineName, OBJPROP_STYLE, STYLE_SOLID);
      
      ObjectCreate(0, P_25_Name, OBJ_TREND, 0, startTime, P_25, endTime, P_25);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, P_25_Name, OBJPROP_COLOR, clrBlue);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, P_25_Name, OBJPROP_WIDTH, 1);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, P_25_Name, OBJPROP_STYLE, STYLE_SOLID);
      
      ObjectCreate(0, P_50_Name, OBJ_TREND, 0, startTime, P_50, endTime, P_50);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, P_50_Name, OBJPROP_COLOR, clrYellow);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, P_50_Name, OBJPROP_WIDTH, 1);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, P_50_Name, OBJPROP_STYLE, STYLE_SOLID);
      
      ObjectCreate(0, P_75_Name, OBJ_TREND, 0, startTime, P_75, endTime, P_75);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, P_75_Name, OBJPROP_COLOR, clrOrange);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, P_75_Name, OBJPROP_WIDTH, 1);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, P_75_Name, OBJPROP_STYLE, STYLE_SOLID);

      ObjectCreate(0, lowLineName, OBJ_TREND, 0, startTime, low, endTime, low);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, lowLineName, OBJPROP_COLOR, clrGreen);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, lowLineName, OBJPROP_WIDTH, 1);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, lowLineName, OBJPROP_STYLE, STYLE_SOLID);

      i++;
     }
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
double NormalizeDoubleFunction(double value){
   double point = SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_POINT);
   return NormalizeDouble(value/point, 0) * point;
}


range = int(high - low); is strange or incorrect. try simply double range=high-low; and get back if problem happens again

Thanks alot that helped and worked perfectlt!
